# Unused properties in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, properties, spring-boot

I am having a problem with IntelliJ inspection: It is indicating that all of my properties are unused (see the image). This is untrue, because all my properties all correctly used in spring boot project. I am using IntelliJ Community Edition 2016.1.4

[image: unused properties image]

Comment: The Community Edition doesn't have any Spring integrations. So it doesn't know, when you use the properties in a Spring bean or configuration etc.

Comment: Ow so thats the case.. okay thanks for information :)

Comment: Still about the Community Edition: if you use `.yml` instead, you will get rid with the highlight, but still it won't say if it is in use or not

Comment: I use ultimate version, and it correctly colors the properties that are used/unused in constructor-arg, but those that are used in property are always colored as unused

Answer (score 27):

If you want to ignore all warnings in a specific file. We just have to add this at the first line :

```
# suppress inspection "UnusedProperty" for whole file
```

If you just want to ignore a warning for a single property, you can add this line before the property :

```
# suppress inspection "UnusedProperty"
```

[image: popup menu to suppress warning]
[image: text to add to suppress warning for whole file]

Comment: A better workaround with good explanation than the other one suggested that completely disables the inspection.

Answer (score 9):

Idea -> Preferences -> search "unused" or "Inspections" -> uncheck "Unused Property " under "Properties Files"

Comment: That helps the squiggles go away, but a warning for unused properties is useful.

Also, the unused-properties warning is apparently working for some properties but not others. I'd love to know how it gets hooked up and how to maybe hint to the IDE that the properties are, in fact, being used.

Comment: This is not a good practice to my mind, because it will disable warnings for all properties files. It will work.. But it's not the best solution I think

Comment: @Kane Sun, Is this a solution or a workaround? Is this problem raise up on different version of IntelliJ or do you think the problem is elsewhere? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the plugin is not supporting this feature/annotation which Intellij is then able to resolve. But you could write your own method for that.

So you have to create a method which calls the method which is not capable of creating the connection. The created method has to make us of the @PropertyKey Annotation which will allow Intellij to see the connection for your method and resolve the not used problem you have.

```java
    private static final String BUNDLE_NAME = "application";

    public static void newMethod(@PropertyKey(resourceBundle = BUNDLE_NAME) String key) {
        oldMethod(key) //replace oldMethod with your method
    }
```

By calling the method **foo** it will detect the property connection to the property file if your resources are allocatable.

```
newMethod("your.awesome.key")
```

Answer (score 0):

add library to pom.xml file problem will be solved

```
       <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
          <version>2.7.2</version>
      </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell the IDE which properties are being used. You can do this in Java with the @propertykey annotation:

```
private static final string bundle_name = "application";

public static void doSomething(@propertykey(resourcebundle = bundle_name) string key) {
    // ...
}
```

If you call doSomething("BLAH"), the IDE will know that BLAH is accessed from the "application.properties" file.

In Kotlin, you use the @PropertyKey annotation for the same purpose:

```
fun doSomething(@PropertyKey(resourceBundle = "application") key: String): String {
    // ...
}

val x = doSomething("BLAH")
```

Answer (score -1):

Use final String variable to define the property's key `REGION_CONFIG_KEY`,
Invoke the `property's key` in `@Value("${" + REGION_CONFIG_KEY + "}"`,
So the problem will be fixed

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).